Quarto elsevier template does not render citation
I'm trying to use the elsevier journal template of Quarto.
Following the README, after
quarto use template quarto-journals/elsevier

and
quarto render template.qmd

, in the resulting PDF file the inline citations are rendered as (author?):

Why is that?
And how can I fix it?

This turned out to be a bug in elsarticle which has since been fixed.

I have faced this issue. This template is using natbib so can be resolved by adding this to your preamble:
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 


Response to comment
The above just fixes the issue of inline citations not rendering properly. If you want a different citation style, you should probably not use this template or use a different CSL file. However, you can amend it through making changes to the header. The default cite-style is super. If you want author year style with round brackets you can change the cite-style key which appears under journal:
    journal:
      name: Journal Name
      formatting: preprint
      model: 3p
      cite-style: authoryear


If you don't want the references highlighted you can also add colorlinks: false:
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
          \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
    colorlinks: false


If you want square (rather than round) brackets for the year you can do:
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
          \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={[},close={]}}  
    colorlinks: false
    keep-tex: true
    journal:
      name: Journal Name
      formatting: preprint
      model: 3p
      cite-style: authoryear


Note: I switched from unsrtnat to abbrvnat as I prefer numeric referencing to be in order of appearance in the text, but author year referencing to be in alphabetical order. However, journals will have their own views. See here for the differences between the Natbib bibliography styles.

How can I have author-year?

@robertspierre this is set by the template in elsarticle.cls but you can override it without messing around with that file - see my edit
